# CSV Helper, Write Row to file even in case user closes the app

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, streamwriter, csvhelper

I have to be able to write rows to CSV even when user closes the app in the middle of writing to file. I'm using CSVHelper and it creates my file, but nothing is written to it when I close it during processing. I'm trying to use a loop and write records one by one, but it just creates empty file.

```
           foreach (var item in requestBody)
            {
                result = "somestring"
                var blockResultBody = new BlockResultBody()
                {
                    ID = item.ID ,
                    Result = result
                };

                csv.WriteRecords(new List<BlockResultBody>() { blockResultBody });
                // If I Close app here, I want my row to be written to file.
            }
```

Comment: How're you creating your csv object. Show us the whole code.

Comment: You could have the app detect a close and if a CSV is in the middle of being written, wait a few seconds for it to finish before closing.

Answer (score 0):

You could set your `StreamWriter` to `AutoFlush`.  That way it will flush the stream after each line is written instead of waiting for the buffer to fill before flushing.  This could make the writing to the file slower if it is a larger number of records.

```cs
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var result = "somestring";
    var blockResultBody = new BlockResultBody()
    {
        ID = item.ID,
        Result = result
    };

    writer.AutoFlush = true;

    csv.WriteRecords(new List<BlockResultBody>() { blockResultBody });
}
```